# How to use one button across multiple div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cfml

I'm trying to create a button to handle a voting system poll per post.

Basically, I have this one and only button set, to handle all my request per post in the page. What happens now is that when I click on the button, the same information is requested the amount of post there are in the page. So for example: If I have three post that refer to user **X**,**Y** and **Z**, and I click on the button for the post of user **Y**, this will send 3 request for user **X**, instead of one for user **Y**. So, in simple terms, my problem is that the button doesn't know how to differentiate one post from another.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fd85e1d44c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
        <cfinclude template="../css/menu.css">
        <cfinclude template="../css/login.css">
        <cfinclude template="../css/search.css">
        <cfinclude template="../css/createPost.css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<!---
    Create mainPageData() method object used to return all posts
--->
<cfset local.mainData = createObject("component", "index").mainPageData()>

<div class="container">
<cfoutput query="local.mainData">
        <div class="column">
        <cfset local.fetchModelData = createObject("component", "Fanexus.tools.tools").voteOnModelTwo(local.mainData.post_id, local.mainData.post_model_username)>
        <cf_voteOnModel model="#local.fetchModelData.post_model_name#" id="#local.fetchModelData.post_id#" path="./index.cfc">
        </div>
</cfoutput>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the snippet for the AJAX in <cf_voteOnModel model> customTag.

```
<cfoutput>
    <button type="button" name="clickBtn" id="clickBtn">CLICK</button>
</cfoutput>

<cfparam name="Attributes.model" default="">
<cfparam name="Attributes.id" default="">
<cfparam name="Attributes.path" default="">

<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        voteOnModel = function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<cfoutput>#Attributes.path#</cfoutput>',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    model_name: '<cfoutput>#Attributes.model#</cfoutput>',
                    method: 'voteOnModel',
                    returnFormat: 'json'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert("YAY " + data[1].text);
                }
            });
        }


        // $("#clickBtn").click(function (){
        $("div.column").click(function (){
            alert('IM HERE');
            voteOnModel();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any advices on how to address this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you post your resulting html of <div class="container">, however, you can solve this by using unique ID's of elements when submitting votes. I don't see where are you sending the specific ID's to your voteOnModel function.

Comment: You need to pass data when clicking the button and use/pass that information in your voteOnModel function, so you can work with it further.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasRu, your comment gave me an idea on how to solve the issue.